# Restore Out the Box Process

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration, azure-devops-migration-tools

I am moving from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps in the cloud.
Following the migration guide I have done the following:

TFS 2015 -> TFS 2018 -> DevOps 2020.

When running the Migrator tool I am getting an error. The OTB process has errors in them.

If I don't care about the changes made in my process is there a simple way to get to the OTB process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process validation error in TryMatchOobProcesses.log file would block your projects
from landing in the inherited process model(OTB process). But You don't have to fix these errors. They will not prevent you from doing an import. And all your customizations will be imported to Hosted XML process model.

See below extracts from the [Process template validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-processtemplates?view=azure-devops-2020#process-validation-types).

> If the project was created with the Agile, Scrum, or CMMI process template, and was never customized, the project will use the Inheritance process model. In all other cases, the data migration tool considers the project as customized, and the project will use the Hosted XML process model.

> TryMatchOobProcesses.log - Lists for each project the target process model - Inheritance or Hosted XML. For projects that are set to target the Hosted XML process model, it explains why they are considered to be customized. You don't have to fix these errors, but they give you guidance what to do in case you want to migrate into the Inheritance process model

And now DevOps 2020 services supports [Moving from Hosted XML Process to Inherited Process](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/moving-from-hosted-xml-process-to-inherited-process-ga/). See the below official documents for more information about what you need to pay attention to when moving to Inherited Process.

- [Clone a Hosted XML process to an Inheritance process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/upgrade-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops)
- [Change a project from Hosted XML to an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-from-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops)

So according to Document and the [Migration Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274)(Page-33), you can just import the process without fixing the Process validation error in TryMatchOobProcesses.log. After the process is imported to Hosted XML process. Then you can change it to the Inheritance process.